# Can't figure out this shape

Tags: modeling

I'm still very new to blender and i'm capable of doing some weird shapes but for the life of me i can't figure out what i need to do to obtain this shape. I almost had it but not quite and forgot to save, now i'm puzzled again. If someone could please give me some advice on how to get this shape i would GREATLY! appreciate it as it's vital to my model [I suppose every shape is lol].I've included a pic of the shape and a pic of the model I am working on
P.S  i'm not even a modeler  this just a hobby i recently got into and I'm loving the process of learning and creating. [image]

Comment: I'm starting with a cube, cutting the arch with a cylinder but can't seem to get the bevel of the roof shape right.

Comment: I might just go with the background image, trace with a vertice and extrude technique but i did it once and it looked funky.

Comment: Mirror Modifier, Curve Modifier Along with your extrude.

Comment: You have no reason to put comments on your question unless they are responses to questions.

Comment: could you please show what you've tried so far? (wireframe)

Comment: can you upload more then one picture in a post?. if not i got an idea on how to show each step in one pic. But can you help with a problem I'm having with normals?. I've made sure my normals were all facing the same direction on mesh but when i import to unreal engine the mesh is solid on the outside and when you go inside you can see through to the environment on the front and back part of the roof. I think it's because besides those two pieces the rest of the mesh has depth i.e wall thickness, the pieces i mentioned that are see through are only plane pieces so i think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a plane and then extrude the edge to create the basic shape:

[image]

Then add edge loops to get a decent quad mesh

[image]

Note that the loops going around are close to the edge.

Make sure the pivot point is at the top centre and the two verts are scaled to zero to make sure they are in line.

[image]

add a mirror modifier and apply it. Then add a couple of sharpening cuts on either side of the centre line.

[image]

Select all faces and extrude x 3 with the start and end extrude being close to the edge.

[image]

Add a subsurface x 2

[image]

I did this very quickly but you can adjust the initial block out verts to shape it with the image. The image is not great quality but I am sure you will do it better with more time.

Comment: Awesome! I'll give it a go this evening and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

How do i go about doing that?. i don't see anything to tick it as answered and i just started using this website two days ago but briefly each time i visited. Also i decided to go with bezier curve to achieve the shape but now i have another issue. it won't let me extrude the shape, when i slide the extrude slider the bezier curve just vanishes. I did one side of the shape and used a mirror modifier then attempted the extrude but it's not working. Is it due to the mirror modifier or do i need to draw the entire shape connecting the points to form the complete shape first?. Also how do i mark my post as answered again?.[image]

Comment: This should be a comment on my original answer. If you want to use a spline then its a completely different process than the one described earlier. Best to follow some spline tutorials first. Maybe this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-zwwS9AkUw

Answer (score 0):

Well i couldn't get the bezier curve to extrude properly and although your technique looked like it would of worked well i still haven't tried it yet. Instead i went back to starting with a plane, forming a cube and proportionally scaling along the edges. I think with some tweaking i'll get it to look just right. I'm still going to give your idea a shot later but this is what i came up with starting with a plane.[image]

Comment: Do you know a way to get straight edge loops after an extrusion resulting in a peak or triangle?. If so i can go back and adjust those spaces that are showing.